# Why is this code only gives last lrow of matrix, not complete matrix?

Tags: c, matrix, mpi

My code in MPI using C is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>


int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    int num_procs;
    int rank;
    int n;
    int lst[n];
    // int lst2[n];
    int matrix[n][n];

    MPI_Status status;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv); 
    MPI_Comm_size (MPI_COMM_WORLD, &num_procs); 
    MPI_Comm_rank (MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank); 
    //printf("%d: hello (p=%d)\n", rank, num_procs);
    
    n=num_procs;

    if (rank==0){

        for (int i=0;i<n;i++) {
            lst[i]=(i+1)*(rank+1);
            // printf("%d ",lst[i]);
        }
        // printf("\n");

        for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
            matrix[0][i]=lst[i];
        }

        for (int k=1;k<num_procs;k++){
            MPI_Recv(&lst,n,MPI_INT,k,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
            
            for (int j=0;j<n;j++){
                matrix[k][j]=lst[j];
            }

            // for (int i=0;i<n;i++) {
            //     printf("%d ",lst[i]);
            // }
            // printf("\n");
        }

        for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
            for (int j=0;j<n;j++){
                printf("%d ", matrix[i][j]);
                if (j==n-1){printf("\n");}
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        for (int i=0;i<n;i++) {
            lst[i]=(i+1)*(rank+1);
            // printf("%d ",lst[i]);
        }
        // printf("\n");

        MPI_Send(&lst[0],n,MPI_INT,0,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
    
    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

This gives:

```
4 8 12 16 
4 8 12 16 
4 8 12 16 
4 8 12 16
```

But expected answer is:

```
1 2 3 4 
2 4 6 8 
3 6 9 12 
4 8 12 16
```

After cross checking, I know I used `MPI` function correctly and my print function is also correct, so my guess is, there is some error in this part:

```
            for (int j=0;j<n;j++){
                matrix[k][j]=lst2[j];
            }
```

But I don't know what is getting know even after so many cross checking.

Can you explain me where am I wrong and what should I do to correct it?

Comment: `n` has not been assigned any value when you define the VLAs `lst[n]` and `matrix[n][n]`. Unlike a spreadsheet, C uses the value known at the time.

Comment: @WeatherVane Yeah if I define them later, I got the answer but why is it giving that answer if I use above code

Comment: It is *undefined behaviour*. There is little point speculating why incorrect code behaved the way it did, unless you need to prove that a bug was caused by apparently unrelated code.

Comment: No, I was just curious about why it still created 4x4 matrix even though `n` is not assigned any value and why it overwrite each time and only give last row repeated again and again.

Comment: Apparently it does not create a 4x4 matrix. That illusion comes from the loops, which have the correct value for `n`. The arrays do not.

Comment: Thanks! After changing loop, it does go beyond. I understand.